# What is the best data structure for removing an element from the middle?

Tags: c++, stack

The data stucture must be like a stack. Only with one difference. I want to pop from any index not only last. When I have popped element `n`, the elements with indexes `N > n` must swap to `N-1`. Any ideas?

P.S.

1. Pushing element `n` into the last index of the stack.
2. Then popping it out.
3. Then deleting `stack[n]`

is a bad idea.

Comment: Any time complexity constraint?

Comment: I have never in my life wanted a linked list.  Have you profiled your code?

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for a linked list.

Comment: Agreed, `std::list` is the right choice. But, if he has some unstated reason to prefer `std::vector`, it would work, using `std::vector::erase()` for the behavior he asks for.

Answer (score 1):

A linked list (`std::list`) will allow you to remove an element from the middle with `O(1)` complexity and automatically "pull" up the elements after it. You can use a linked list like a stack by using `push_front`. However you need to be aware that accessing an element in a linked list is `O(n)` as you would need to start at the head of the list and then walk along the links from one element to the next until you have arrived at element `n` (so there is no `O(1)` indexing)

Basically you would need to

- Create an iterator
- `advance` it to position `n`
- Get the element from the iterator
- `erase` the element the iterator is currently pointing to

Some example code can be found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/erase/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a linked list, but unlike an array, the order in a linked list is determined by a pointer in each object. So, you cannot use indices to access the elements.

Comment: you can't use an index, but you do have `auto iter = std::advance(mylist.begin(), 42);`